# Tkinter randomly freezing when a new line of code added

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a tkinter clock program however it randomly freezes after a few seconds. This behaviour just began and I have no idea why. It started when I added this line to my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import threading

global TimerOn
TimerOn = False

root = Tk()
root.title("Alarm Clock")
root.geometry("500x500")

TimerVar = 0
Time = Label(root, text = f"{time}", font = ("Times New Roman", 50))
Time.place(x = "160", y = "100")
Timer = Label(root, text = f"{TimerVar}")

def TimerUpdate():
    global TimerVar
    TimerVar = TimerVar - 1
    Timer.config(text = f"{TimerVar}")
    root.after(1000, TimerUpdate)

def Update():
    global TimerOn
    now = datetime.now()
    time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    Time.config(text = f"{time}")
    if TimerOn == True:
        root.after(1000, TimerUpdate)
        #TimerOn = False  # Problematic line.
    else:
        root.after(1000, Update)

    root.after(1000, Update)

def AppendTime():
    global TimerVar
    TimerVar = TimerVar + 60
    Timer.config(text = f"{TimerVar}")

def DeductTime():
    global TimerVar
    TimerVar = TimerVar - 60
    Timer.config(text = f"{TimerVar}")

HigherTimer = Button(root, text = "+", command = AppendTime, font = ("Times New Roman", 25))
LowerTimer = Button(root, text = "-", command = DeductTime, font = ("Times New Roman", 25))

def Start():
    global TimerOn
    Timer.config(font = ("Times New Roman", 50))
    Timer.place(x = "160", y = "250")
    TimerOn = True

def CreateTimer():
    HigherTimer.pack()
    Timer.pack()
    LowerTimer.pack()
    StartTimer.pack()
    Time.place(x = "160", y = "150")

HigherTimer = Button(root, text = "+", command = AppendTime, font = ("Times New Roman", 25))
LowerTimer = Button(root, text = "-", command = DeductTime, font = ("Times New Roman", 25))
StartTimer = Button(root, text = "Start", command = Start, font = ("Times New Roman", 25))
createTimer = Button(root, text = "Set a timer", command = CreateTimer)
createTimer.pack()
Update()

root.mainloop()
```

And when I'm talking about it "freezing" I mean that since I'm on a mac it says a little "Application not responding" and I have to force quit it to end the program.

Even when I removed the code it still kept on freezing. I have no idea what's happening.

Comment: provide a [mre], currently it is unclear why anything is freezing, seems that it happens due to the `TimerUpdate` function and what do you mean by _freezing_? does it stop updating or does the entire app freeze?

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry, I have made a new post.

Comment: no, you need to [edit] your question to update it, also you need to provide a [mre], not an excerpt from your code

Comment: I am so sorry for the trouble, I believe I have fixed it

Comment: first of it is not a [mre], second it is pretty clear that this is not the code that is causing the issue, there really is nothing in the question that would help solve this problem, you need to provide a [mre] and since you have said that removing these lines doesn't help fixing the issue (which is also why the post doesn't contain anything useful), those can most certainly be removed from the [mre]. A [mre] is basically a new, extremely small piece of code, that is only meant to reproduce the problem at hand, so anything else that is not directly related can be removed from the [mre]

Comment: also a [mre] should be made such that anyone can copy-paste the code from the question to their IDE and run and it will work and reproduce the issue, in terms of how small it should be, I guess like 70 lines max really

Comment: @Matiiss I believe I have fixed it

Comment: Why are you creating `HigherTimer` and `LowerTimer` twice? If not, please edit your question again and fix that.

Comment: remove the `else` block in `Update` function, should fix the issue (which seems to be that you schedule a lot of calls to `Update` which schedule even more of those and that likely hangs `tkinter`, it happens because once the `if` evaluates to `False` you schedule `Update` to be called twice, each time it is called and so the number of functions to be called grows exponentially)